# Как правильно организовать синхронизацию файлов с удаленным хранилищем Firebase

Tags: java, android

Как правильно организовать синхронизацию файлов с удаленным хранилищем Firebase. Может есть хороший паттерн. Суть задачи в следующим: 
Есть приложение на Android (написано на Java). Данное приложение постоянно записывает в файлы в папках приложения данные. Эти данные необходимо синхронизировать со Storage в Firebase. Как лучше всего это сделать?
На данный момент я сделал так:
В методе onStop(), приложение отправляет последнюю версию этих файлов в Storage. 
В методе onStart(), скачивает эти файлы из Storage и меняет в приложении. 
Как то топорно, получилось, но работает. 
Может есть какие определённые паттерны или методы.

Comment: Вы смотрели доку по Firebase? Думаю там должна быть подписка чисто на изменения и будут приходить чисто изменения из Storage. В БД такое есть, думаю в Storage тоже должно быть.

Comment: Смотрел, но нашел)